# How to increase the limit on characters in ODBC

Tags: java, odbc

I got a problem.
I have a .accdb data.(Access Data)
My data column is called remark, size is more than 256byte.

I used odbc Driver

```
 Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

 Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, props);

 PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareSTatement("select * from test");

 rs = ps.executeQuery();

while(rs.next()){

 String remark = rs.getString("remark");

 System.out.println(remark);

}
```

This logic get data truncated 255byte ;

what should I solve problem the limited character size on ODBC?

What can I do get data more than 255 bytes?

help me please, I appreciate it.

Comment: Is it truncated while writing to db or it is already more than 255 bytes in db but you get only 255 byte while reading?

Comment: it truncated while writing to db.

Answer (score 1):

use Jackcess!

I found solve the problem truncating 255byte at 
http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/

finally, i could get data more than 255 byte.

If Someone finding this problem,
use jackcess

```
-announced part omitted-

Table table = db.getTable("TableName");

for(Row row :table){

for(Column column : table.getColumns()){

columnName = column.getName();

value=row.get(columnName); 

ps.setString(index, String);
```